# Installing mysql 5.7 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have mysql 5.5 installed, and need 5.7. Tried to update using this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7/750502#750502

Then tried uninstalling 5.5 and installing from scratch following this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

On the last step I just can install 5.5 again, no 5.7:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Not sure why the new configured repos for 5.7 are not being used.

Comment: Did you try to specify a version? After all the repo contains quite a few versions and 5.5 might still simply be the "stable"/default one for the mysql-server package?

Comment: Do you need at _least_ mysql 5.7 or do you need _exactly_ mysql 5.7? Also, have you checked the _other_ answers in that [askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7/835095#835095)?

Comment: I need JSON columns which 5.5 doesn't to support since was introduced in 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way of installing 5.7 from the repo under ubuntu 14, so closing this for good.